# How click on standart android button in autotest using Ruby, Appium?

Tags: android, ruby, testing, automation

Help Please.

I use:win 7, ruby 2.0.0, appium 1.3.7.0

I test android app.

In test suite, in my steps I define:

`Appium.back`

I try tap on hardware(native) button e.g. back, home.

but if I run test, appears next error :

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'back' for Appium:Module`

Answer (score 0):

ansver to my question

in env.rb write

`$capy_driver = Capybara.current_session.driver`

and use in steps

```
  $capy_driver.go_back
```

or

`$capy_driver.appium_driver.press_keycode 4`